# Doing math in Python with lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, math, subtraction

Say I have a list...  How would I subtract the largest number with the smallest?

```
lst = [23,41,54,65,73]
```

what I figure I do is

```
mth = (lst[4]-lst[1])
```

but how would I make it find the largest number in the list and subtract it with the smallest?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `max` and `min`, which are explained [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

```
>>> lst = [23,41,54,65,73]
>>> max(lst) - min(lst)
50
>>>
```

`max` will get the largest number and `min` will get the smallest.